# Label columns with a ascending number

Tags: r

I want to label columns with a ascending number. The reason is because in a bigger dataset I want to be able to sort the columns so they get in the right order.
 How do i code this? Thanks!

```
set.seed(8)
id <- 1:6
diet <- rep(c("A","B"),3)
period <- rep(c(1,2),3)
score1 <- sample(1:100,6)
score2 <- sample(1:100,6)
score3 <- sample(1:100,6)

df <- data.frame(id, diet, period, score1, score2,score3)
df
 id diet period score1 score2 score3
1  1    A      1     47     30     44
2  2    B      2     21     93     54
3  3    A      1     79     76     14
4  4    B      2     64     63     90
5  5    A      1     31     44      1
6  6    B      2     69      9     26
```

It should look like:

```
x1id x2diet x3period x4score1 x5score2 x6score3
1    1      A        1       47       30       44
2    2      B        2       21       93       54
3    3      A        1       79       76       14
4    4      B        2       64       63       90
5    5      A        1       31       44        1
6    6      B        2       69        9       26
```

I was thinking something like this, but something is missing....
colnames(wellbeing) <- paste(1:ncol, colnames(wellbeing))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
names(df) <- paste0('x', seq_along(df), names(df))
df

#  x1id x2diet x3period x4score1 x5score2 x6score3
#1    1      A        1       96        1       52
#2    2      B        2       52       93       75
#3    3      A        1       55       50       68
#4    4      B        2       79        3        9
#5    5      A        1       12        6       76
#6    6      B        2       42       86       62
```

Maybe add an underscore?

```
names(df) <- paste0('x', seq_along(df), "_", names(df))
names(df)
#[1] "x1_id"     "x2_diet"   "x3_period" "x4_score1" "x5_score2" "x6_score3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another options:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0('x', 1:dim(df)[2], colnames(df))
```

or

```
df %>%
  dplyr::rename_all(~ paste0('x', 1:ncol(df), .))
```

Both methods would yield the same output:

```
#  x1id x2diet x3period x4score1 x5score2 x6score3
#1    1      A        1       96        1       52
#2    2      B        2       52       93       75
#3    3      A        1       55       50       68
#4    4      B        2       79        3        9
#5    5      A        1       12        6       76
#6    6      B        2       42       86       62
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `mapply` approach.

```
mapply(paste0, paste0("x", 1:ncol(df)), names(df))
```